# Bash: exit in script doesn't close terminal

Tags: linux, bash

I'm working on a script to run on terminal like this one

```
#!/bin/bash
COUNTER=0
         while [  $COUNTER -lt 10 ]; do
             echo The counter is $COUNTER
             yoooooooo
             sleep 2
             let COUNTER=COUNTER+1 
         done

exit
```

But once the counter reaches 9 and the while cycle stops, the terminal wont close with the command "exit".

Here's the output

```
pi@raspberrypi:~/Desktop $ ./sxdd
The counter is 0
./sxdd: line 7: yoooooooo: command not found
The counter is 1
./sxdd: line 7: yoooooooo: command not found
The counter is 2
./sxdd: line 7: yoooooooo: command not found
The counter is 3
./sxdd: line 7: yoooooooo: command not found
The counter is 4
./sxdd: line 7: yoooooooo: command not found
The counter is 5
./sxdd: line 7: yoooooooo: command not found
The counter is 6
./sxdd: line 7: yoooooooo: command not found
The counter is 7
./sxdd: line 7: yoooooooo: command not found
The counter is 8
./sxdd: line 7: yoooooooo: command not found
The counter is 9
./sxdd: line 7: yoooooooo: command not found
pi@raspberrypi:~/Desktop $
```

And it never quits... how do I fix that?

Comment: What terminal? How are you running this script?

Comment: @melpomene I'm using linux. I used che chmod command to run the script on the terminal by doing ./script

Comment: There's nothing to fix, then. `exit` exits your script, as designed.

Comment: @anubhava yes it is on a text file. I forgot to mention that there is "#!/bin/bash" at the beginning of the script

Comment: @melpomene look at the updated description so you can see the output I get...

Comment: What does that have to do with anything I said?

Comment: @melpomene you said that the `exit` command after the while cycle will exit the script, but it won't lol... did I get you wrong?

Comment: The `exit` command did exit the script. And then you were back at your shell prompt, ready to run the next command: `pi@raspberrypi:~/Desktop $ `

Answer (score 3):

> the terminal wont close with the command "exit"

That's because you run the exit command inside a script. There `exit` means "exit the script", not "exit the terminal".
If you want to close the terminal window from a script, you probably have to use commands like `kill $pidOfTheTerminalWindow`.

As an alternative, you can *source* the script, that is execute the script as if you typed it directely into the command line. Use either

```
source sxdd
```

or

```
. sxdd
```

Comment: Alternatively, run the script commands directly in the current shell with `. ./sxdd`.

Comment: @melpomene thank you your solution works fine ;) if you write it as an answer I'll accept that

Answer (score 2):

Try to run your script like this:
`exec ./sxdd`

It replaces the shell process with your script and when the script exits your window will close.